# Run a batch file from Java program and get the status of execution

Tags: java

I need to run a Batch file from my Java Program and know if that was completed or not.

```
try{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );

    if( null!=process  && process.waitFor() == 0 &&process.exitValue()== 0 )
     {
        LOGGER.debug("Command executed successfuly.["+command+"]");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        LOGGER.debug( "Error while getting the modified log" );
        return 1;
    }
}
catch( IOException e ){
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch( InterruptedException e ){
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My command is something similar to this `cmd /c C:/Test/test.bat`
This `test.bat` file takes some 10-15 minutes to complete. Immediately after this is executed, `process.exitValue()` returns `0`. But I need to know if this was executed completely or not. In my `test.bat` file, I'm calling another exe file which performs some operations. That exe file writes some error information to the console.I need to get that information.

Is it possible to know this from Java code? Or Can someone please let me know the best way to check this?
I thought of some approaches like writing the status(after successful completion) to a text file (from the batch program) and then check this from Java code. But I don't think that is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execString);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("Result: " + IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream()));
   log.debug("Error: " + IOUtils.toString(process.getErrorStream()));
}
if (process.waitFor() == 0) { .. }
```

Comment: Suppose in my test.bat file I call another exe file to perform some operation. Does process.getErrorStream() returns error information if that exe file writes some error to the console?

Comment: I'm able to get that, but the problem is my batch file takes some 15-20 mins to execute, How do I know that the execution is completed?

Comment: Waitfor will block until it is complete

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your file test.bat does, but I wouldn't try to parse the output stream if I could change that bat file. Change test.bat so that it actually uses exit codes, and define exit codes so that they indicate what type of error you have.

The value returned by waitFor will then indicate if the execution terminated successfully, or how it failed if it failed.

Btw. You should always read stdout and stderr from processes since execution can halt if the buffers for those streams get full.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to return exit codes from a Batch program based on conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Process.getOutputStream(). See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: If that Batch file takes some 15-20 minutes to complete, then I should check the output stream at frequent intervals right? Or am I thinking in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from this site.
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4